# Определить какие папки открыты в Проводнике Windows (Windows Explorer)

Tags: windows, файлы, файловая-система, explorer

Можно ли каким то образом программно определить какие папки в данный момент открыты в Проводнике Windows (Windows Explorer). Идея заключается в том, чтобы перезапустить проводник и открыть в нём именно те папки, которые были открыты до момента перезапуска.

Comment: Интереса ради воспользуйтесь утилитой типа Microsoft Spy++. В комплекте AutoIt есть аналогичная для работы с окнами. С помощью них можно найти окна (ToolbarWindow), в которых прописан адрес открытого каталога. В Windows 10 может не сработать по причине отсутствия таких объектов у Проводника.

Answer (score 0):

в винде опцию можно включить в настройках "Восстановить предыдущие окна папок при входе в систему", итого при перезапуске проводника, они восстановятся.

Чисто кодом прочитать содержимое окна нельзя. Но можно через WinAPI GetWindowText попробовать читать заголовки, опять же, если включена опция "отображать весь путь в заголовке" вы получите список путей.

Comment: Эта опция срабатывает только при перезагрузке ПК

Comment: проверяли ? у меня она работает при перезапуске explorer.exe , сразу открываются окна которые были открыты до его закрытия. Даже если я рестарт этого процесса делаю из диспетчера задач.

Comment: Конечно проверял. Не работает (